# How to unittest if __name__ == '__main__'

Tags: python, mocking, unit-testing

I would like to unittest the lines behind `__main__`, but don't know how to mock them:

```
class X:
   def y(self):
     ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
  X().y()
```

I want to unittest exactly these lines not the function itself!

I tried for example these:

For example:

```
@mock.patch('module_a.X.y')
def test_y_called_in_main(self, mock_y):
  import module_a
  mock_y.assert_any_call()
```

or..

```
@mock.patch('module_a.X.y')
def test_y_called_in_main(self, mock_y):
  imp.load_source('__main__', path_to_X)
  mock_y.assert_any_call()
```

Comment: How do you mean exactly? I tried couple of ways.. but it was not working

Comment: OK. I know that... the problem is that how do you call if __name__ == '__main__' part. The function can be mocked, but for example with imp.load_source it has no effect.

Comment: i have added examples. please check

Comment: Have you checked the other answers to the duplicate?

Comment: Yes, as I see the answer is to exclude those lines...i cannot accept it.

Comment: I'm not talking about the accepted answer. I'm talking about the other answers, like the one by Robru.

Comment: I did. How does it ensure that the function actually called like this? run_script(__name__, __doc__, main)... in my opinion i could right a code which passes those tests but actually the script can be imported also ;) i mean what if I say in src: run_script('something_stupid', __doc__, main)